# Basic question about normal mapping with two merged meshes (but not joined)

Tags: normals, normal-map

I'm hoping that this is a simple question and answer.  I have a default cube.  I have created an additional torus mesh and rotated and place it slightly into the cube's front face (giving the appearance of a poor camera lense for starters).  This is a test that I was using to calculate a normal map using cylces as the baker.

I have already smart UV unwrapped it (and while it's not joined) they both are selected as one (didn't have to do anything special here).  Note: The UV map shows all of the faces as expected (the torus and the cube - I can even paint the torus via UV texturing).

Here's the blender file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/13d508b19ad7466aa548e3be4a186b23

My basic question is this, when I bake a normal map, it shows flat, as if it's looking at the cube only.  How do I get the normal bake to show the normals (as shown via display normals) including the torus that's slightly pushed into the cube?

Thanks

Comment: Hi :). You can share the file through https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Will add now!

Comment: Okay, now the edit got lost ... :/ here's the link
https://pasteall.org/blend/13d508b19ad7466aa548e3be4a186b23
[edit] if someone knows where the edit button has gone in stackexchannge that'd be great to know, thanks!